# Traditional Computer Vision techniques for analyzing LiDAR data

Tags: lidar, lidar-data

I am currently looking into LiDAR data, and I was wondering are there any Computer Vision only techniques for object recognition/reconstruction for this kind of data? All the methods I have looked into have some form of Machine Learning/Deep Learning involved. I am still a novice so pardon me if my question seems weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that your question looks very weird. Maybe you're searching for the tradition approach (hand-designed feature, ransac, etc). If it's the case then [pcl_tutorials (old but good)](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/) or [open3d (new and good too)](http://www.open3d.org/) is your friend here. Go there and find the method you need.

To be honest, you need to have a brief knowledge of point cloud data processing first. Before lurking into the above document, I recommend reading the [matlab point cloud data processing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/lidar-and-point-cloud-processing.html) or better grabbing some book about point cloud data processing.

Good luck